# Equivalent of Perl's 'pack' function in Java

Tags: java, pack

In Perl, I have the following line of code:

```
pack( "C (N)$cnt", $cnt , @items);
```

I'm having issues transposing this to Java. How can I do it?

Comment: I don't know any Perl. If I knew what that code was doing I might be able to help.

Comment: I inspected the API for DatatypeConverter and I didn't see how I could pack my list into unsigned longs (32-bit) in "network" (big-endian) order.

Comment: @skyer you could use java's nio outputs using `ByteBuffer.allocate(size).order(endianness).asIntBuffer()` to setup an IntBuffer with endian the way you need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Perl is pretty rusty but after looking at `man perlfunc` I think this may be what you want:

```
List<Integer> items = ...;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(baos);
stream.write(items.size());
for (Integer item : items) {
    stream.writeInt(item);
}
stream.flush(); // not sure this is strictly necessary
byte[] result = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: 1) I'm curious why stream.writeInt() worked and not stream.wrtiteLong(). Is that because a Java Int is interpreted as an unsigned long? If so, what is a Java Long interpreted as?
2) baos.toString() is what I needed, thanks.

Comment: A `long` in Java is 64 bits, an `int` is 32 bits. Signed vs. unsigned doesn't matter when you're just writing them, since it doesn't change the representation. `baos.toString()` uses whatever the default platform encoding is. You might want to explicitly specify an encoding e.g., `baos.toString("UTF-8")`.

Comment: Does stream.write() write 1 byte or 4 bytes? According to the Javadoc [1], it appears to be 1 byte.

[1] http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#write(int)

Comment: Yes, that's right, 1 byte. Doesn't `"C"` in Perl `pack` write one byte? As I said, my Perl is very rusty.

Comment: `man perlfunc`, under `pack`, for `C`, says: "An unsigned char (octet) value."